# reloadSections in UITableView bounces to top

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

In my `UITableView` after certain change to model i am trying to load the specific section in where my cells are getting loaded according to the model. But whenever the change happens there comes error with animation, which is like bouncing to top or down. how do i resolve it? So far nothing worked. This is how i am updating my section after api response:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .none)
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()

                }
```

Comment: You are adding /removing heavily from the table? Or only addind or removing 1/2 objects per reload?

Comment: yes all the sections can be updated on request

Comment: If you want it to reload in an elegant way,youcan insert and remove cells instead of reloading. This gets done with animations. Does this satisfy your needs?

Comment: actually not as i have to update only model value and according to which i want to reload it

Comment: Do you still see the "bouncing" if you *only* call `reloadSections()`? That is, do **NOT** wrap it in `begin / end Updates()`...

Comment: yes still the same issue even without begin or end update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i had images of different sizes my `tableview` could not adjust the height calculation while reloading the table. So i have tried to pre calculate the previous height and adjust it to the new one. While implementing the thing it came to my mind that i can update the table from my cell and calling `layoutIfNeeded`would do the trick. So eventually it worked.